# The installed file does not exist - soul.sty

Tags: miktex, texstudio, soul

I want to use this beamer template that I found on Overleaf with MiKTeX in TeXstudio:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/presentation-template-au-theme/ffhvmnbyvdjg

I downloaded the the whole template from Overleaf but unfortunately I get the following
error during compilation:

[image]

Looking at the logs it seems like there is a problem with instaling the soul.sty package:

**The installed file does not exist.**

Do you know a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have installed this package? How you installed it?

Comment: Is there a soul.sty in C:\Program Files\Miktex\tex\latex\soul?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another error now so i think i solved this problem. I manually installed the soul package.

I followed the instructions in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYJkU17Wfnc&t=28s